# Find the area using simultaneous equations

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

So the question is to find the areas A - G.

You are told that the vertical length is 4 and horizontal length is 28

[image]

---

I started making a load of simultaneous equations but found there was too many variables that left me not being able to solve what first appeared to be a straight forward question.

Does anyone know of a simpler route forward? Or is it just identifying which simultaneous equations need using when?

Comment: Are all lengths and areas integers?

Comment: Instead of setting up the entire system, try to look for "corners" of rectangles where you know three values but not the fourth, For example, you can say $10 / 2 = 5/G$ because these pairs of rectangles have the same heights.

Comment: @Mason "You are told that the vertical length is 4 and horizontal length is 28".  Hence my question.  Please read the question carefully, as I did.

Comment: @Frpzzd. I think that they cannot be.

Comment: The rectangle below A has area 10, @Mason, we don't know yet what the area of rectangle A is.

Comment: @amWhy. Yup. We are on the same page.

Comment: Ben Franks  It's your job to fill in the context (where did you find this question - i.e., cite the source of the question; what is your motivation for asking the question; what have you yourself tried).

Comment: @amWhy it was a problem given to me by a teacher at school as an extension but I couldn't work it out, no idea where they got it from. I am interesting in knowing how to solve it. My working is a mess and just lead in circles so I didn't see benefits in posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$10: 2$ as $5: G$. That type of thinking should get you there.

More hints:

> [[image]] Applying this reasoning and you should arrive at something like the image above. And now we have to solve the following $$36c+4/c=72\implies 9c^2+1=18c$$ And this has two solutions $c= 1\pm\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}$

Comment: Did you come to a unique solution?

Comment: I am familiar with quadratics, I will see where I get to with this hint, thank you @Mason.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93.  Two solutions.